# What should I put in the rel attribute for an internal link?

Tags: html, joomla, hyperlink, tinymce, rel

I am using the TinyMCE (extended) that ships with Joomla.

When I use the link button to link an image to another page on the site it asks me to select an option for the 'rel' attribute within the href.

I am a bit confused about this - what value should I put for an internal link? I looked here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_rel.asp but it didn't really help. The select defaults to 'alternate' - which isn't really right.

If I use the 'article' button, my image is deleted and replaced with the title of the article.

What should I put?

Comment: Please check: [section 6.12](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.6).

Comment: thanks - but none of those really seems to imply an internal link... although I suppose at a push you could say 'next' but still doesn't feel right to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming HTML5.)

There is no registered link type for "internal links". There are various link types that might be appropriate for *some* internal links, but not generally for *all* internal links. (And you are right that `alternate` is not appropriate.)

The registered `external` link type can be [used for external links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19638774/1591669), so one might assume that every link without the `external` link type is an internal link.

Comment: Thanks. Seems weird to me that in tinymce you are forced into selecting a value for the rel. you can't leave it blank

Comment: @maxelcat: If TinyMCE really requires a value for the `rel` attribute, this would not be in line with the spec, as `rel` is an optional attribute (which makes sense, because there is not a suitable link type for every case).

Comment: should i be using `rel='external'` for a `form` element if the script that processes the form is a PHP file elsewhere on the back-end of the server?