# How to cite a blog post using HTML microdata and schema.org?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, citations

My goal is to cite a blog post by using HTML microdata.

**How can I improve the following markup for citations?**

I am seeking improvements on the syntax and semantics, to produce a result that works well with HTML5 standards, renders well in current browsers, and parses well in search engines.

The bounty on this question is for expert advice and guidance. My research is turning up many opinions and snippets, so I'm seeking clear answers, complete samples, and canonical documentation.

This is my work in progress and I'm seeking advice on it's correctness:

1. Use `<div class="citation">` to wrap everything.
2. Use `<article>` with `itemscope` and `BlogPost` to wrap the post info including its nested info.
3. Use `<header>` and `<h1 itemprop="headline">` to wrap the post name link.
4. Use `<cite>` to wrap the post name.
5. Use `<footer>` to wrap the author info and blog info.
6. Use `<address>` to wrap the author link and name.
7. Use `rel="author"` to annotate the link to the author's name.
8. Use `itemprop="isPartOf"` to connect the post to the blog.

This is my work in progress HTML source:

```
<!-- Hello World authored by Alice posted on Bob's blog -->
<div class="citation">
  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <header>
      <h1 itemprop="headline">
        <a itemprop="url" href="…">
          <cite itemprop="name">Hello World</cite>
        </a>
      </h1>
    </header>
    <footer>
      authored by
      <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <address>
          <a itemprop="url" rel="author" href="…">
            <span itemprop="name">Alice</span>
          </a>
        </address>
      </span>
      posted on
      <span itemprop="isPartOf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
        <a itemprop="url" href="…">
          <span itemprop="name">Bob's blog</span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </footer>
  </article>
</div>
```

Related notes thus far:

- The `<cite>` tag W3 reference says the tag is "phrase level", so it works like an inline span, not a block div. But the `<article>` tag seems to benefit from using `<h1>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`. As best I can tell, the spec does not give a solution for citing an article by using `<cite>` to wrap `<article>`. Is there a solution to this or a workaround? (The work in progress fudges this by using `<div class="citation">`)
- The `<address>` tag W3 reference says the content "The address element must not be used to represent arbitrary addresses, unless those addresses are in fact the relevant contact information." As best I can tell, the spec does not give a solution for marking the article's author's URL and name, as distinct from the article's contact info. Is there a solution for this or a workaround? (The work in progress fudges this by using `<address>` for the author's URL and name)

Please ask questions in the comments. I will update this post as I learn more.

Comment: "*What is the best markup to use?*" - define 'best.' Also, you might want to explain how this question is *not* "opinion-based."

Comment: To make it not opinion-based you might ask what the standard (as in standards documents) way is, or what search engines understand (which can be supported by their documentation for webmasters).

Comment: Where does such a citation appear, what is its context?

Comment: @unor The context is this: I'm creating a typical readme.html page for an open source project. The page has a "See Also" section that contains a list of citations i.e. a list of links to blog posts.

Comment: There are multiple coding errors here. `cite` is an inline style and you're wrapping it around multiple blocks (h1, article, footer, and header). I also want to say `address` is also misused, unless the URL goes to a page with her contact info.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I updated the cite tag because of your feedback. Can you say more about your address point? I'd like to understand more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you’d ask me which markup to use for a list of links to blog posts ([OP’s context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221558/how-to-cite-a-blog-post-using-html-microdata-and-schema-org#comment42947435_27221558)), without seeing your example, I’d go with something like this:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

<ul>
  <li>
    <cite itemprop="citation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
      <a href="…" itemprop="url" rel="external"><span itemprop="name headline">Hello World</span></a>, 
      authored by <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><a href="…" itemprop="url" rel="external"><span itemprop="name">Alice</span></a></span>,
      posted on <span itemprop="isPartOf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork"><a href="…" itemprop="url" rel="external"><span itemprop="name">Bob’s blog</span></a></span>.
    </cite>
  </li>
  <li>
    <cite itemprop="citation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">…</cite>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
```

---

Using the sectioning content element [`article`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-article-element), like in your example, is certainly possible, although perhaps unusual (if I understand your use case correctly): As `article` is a sectioning content element, it creates an entry in the document outline, which may or may not be what you want for your case. (You can [check the outline with the *HTML5 Outliner*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2191/60), for example.)

Another indication that a sectioning content element might not be the best choice: Your `article` doesn’t contain any actual "main" content. Simply said, the main content of a sectioning content element could be determined by stripping its metadata: `header`, `footer`, and `address` elements. (This is not a explicitly specified, but it follows from the defintions in [Sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#sections).)

However, not having this content is not *wrong*. And one could easily imagine (and maybe you intend to do so anyway) that you’ll quote a snippet from the blog post (making this case [similar to a search result entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970336/1591669)), in which case you’d have:

```
<article>
  <header></header>
  <blockquote></blockquote> <!-- the non-metadata part of the article -->
  <footer></footer>
</article>
```

I’ll further on assume that you want to use `article`.

Notes about your HTML5:

- Semantically, the wrapping `div` is not needed. You could add the `citation` class to the `article` directly.
- The [`header` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-header-element) is [optional if it just contains a heading element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25324129/1591669) (this element makes sense when your header consists of more than just a heading element). However, having it is not wrong, of course.
- I’d prefer to include the `a` element in the [`cite` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) (similar to the fifth example in the spec).
- The `span` element can only contain [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), so `address` isn’t allowed as a child.
- The [`address` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-address-element) must only be used if it contains contact information. So if this element is appropriate depends on what is available at the linked page: if it’s a contact form, yes; if it’s a list of authored blog posts, no.
- The [`author` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#link-type-author) might not be appropriate, as it’s defined to give information about the author of the `article` element. But, strictly speaking, *you* are the author. If the `article` would consist only of the blog post author’s actual content, using the `author` link type would be appropriate; but in your case, you are writing the content ("authored by", "posted on").
- You might want to use the [`external` link type](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-external) for [all external links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19638774/1591669).

Notes about your Microdata:

- You can specify the Schema.org properties `headline` and `name` [in the same `itemprop` (separated with space)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216506/1591669).
- You might want to use Schema.org’s [`citation` property](http://schema.org/citation) on the `article` (which requires that you specify a parent type of [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) or one of its child types; i.e., it could be [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) or maybe even [`AboutPage`](http://schema.org/AboutPage) in your case).

Taking your example, this would give:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

<article itemprop="citation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" class="citation">
    <header>
      <h1>
          <cite itemprop="headline name"><a itemprop="url" href="…" rel="external">Hello World</a></cite>
      </h1>
    </header>
    <footer>
      authored by
      <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
          <a itemprop="url" href="…" rel="external"><span itemprop="name">Alice</span></a>
      </span>
      posted on
      <span itemprop="isPartOf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
        <a itemprop="url" href="…" rel="external"><span itemprop="name">Bob’s blog</span></a>
      </span>
    </footer>
</article>

</body>
```

(All things considered, I still prefer the *section*-less variant.)